# Parsing HTTP response as it arrives

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory-management

My Web API, **AAA**, calls another API, **BBB**, to retrieve a large JSON array (~500-1000 KB and each object is 10 KB), it needs to parse the JSON array to apply a logic on it and forward the response to API **CCC**.

For optimization, I'd like that my Web API AAA doesn't have store the HTTP response containing the large JSON array, so the array doesn't have to be stored in the LOH (Large Object Heap).

I think a good idea to solve this issue is: instead of waiting for the full JSON array to be downloaded, is it possible to parse the elements of the response as it arrives so I can parse it, apply a logic on it and forward the content to my API **CCC**?

So my Web API never gets to store the large JSON array in memory. By parsing each object as it arrives, the object is so small that it will be stored in GEN 0 and gets collected really fast by GC.

What I tried so far:

My API BBB looks like this (simplified):

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\John\\generated1000objects.json");
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(text);
    return Ok(deserialized);
}
```

My code to query

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost:44328/api/values/4"))
using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
using (Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
    while (true)
    {
         if (!reader.Read())
         {
                break;
         }

         JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
         var deserialize = serializer.Deserialize<object>(reader);

         Console.WriteLine(deserialize); // HERE it prints the whole JSON Array. I was expecting to deal with one object of the array
         Console.WriteLine("#################");

     }
}
```

My constraints:

- I can't modify the API **BBB** that send the large JSON array.
- My API CCC cannot directly call API BBB to retrieve the large JSON array

I'm on .NET Core with ASP.NET Core 2.2.

Comment: I don't think this is possible really, at least not with JSON.Net. I have a feeling that you either need to find a library already built or manually process the incoming data stream which won't be much fun.

Comment: @DavidG if they use JTokenReader they can read up to a JToken that is the start of their inner object and then call CreateReader on the CurrentToken to have an instance that can be fed in the Deserialize to return a single instance of each of their objects.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your solution, unless you are expecting this to grow in size substantially I believe that you might be suffering from trying to attempt a micro-optimization that will actually make your process more fragile than by simply processing in a regular manner.

You mention a record size of 10k, a response size of 500-1000k.  This translates to a total of 50-100 records.

I believe that you will experience more difficulties in trying to parse the response in chunks than any impact of having an object on the Large Object Heap will provide.  From what I can find in the various documentation, the ONLY way to parse a JSON document using a built-in library is to parse the whole document.  Any chunking would need to be managed by yourself.